# can i use stripes tag library and spring mvc togther

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stripes

I want to use stripes tag library specifically layout features. My rest of the project is handled by spring mvc.

Is this possible to use stripes without adding any stripes filter?

Answer (score 1):

In the *web.xml* you can [configure](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Quick+Start+Guide) the Stripes *DispatcherServlet* with an *url-pattern* so that Stripes front controller will only respond to certain URL's. Another option is, to use separate context-paths for Stripes and Spring MVC.

Comment: same question here, can you please provide a simple example on how to achieve this? thanks